# Content won't work on different screen sizes in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I built a site using Twitter Bootstrap 3 and I encountered a problem while changing to different screen sizes.
As soon as I go under 991px my buttons and links wont work.
The website is already live so if someone could inspect the elements and tell me what I did wrong and what I have to change.
Also how can I media query the top margin of the carousel so it stays under the navbar and not 50px above?
URL for the site: http://www.dnd-malilosinj.hr/program-i-projekti.html

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in this block of code:

```
            <div class="col-lg-12">
            <nav>
                <ul class="pager">
                    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="projekti/page/2.html">2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            </div>
```

This block in over your code when you are in the middle size. Try **class="col-md-12"** and you'll see the result.

Comment: Didn't work, it has something to do with that container but I can't figure out what's wrong :/

Comment: I've found. class="col-lg-9 pull-left". pull-left - it's your bug.

Comment: Remove "pull-left" from your code. That is why you see some container over your links and when you try to click, you click on this container not on your buttons.

Comment: now I got the pager to work, but the button and image still won't work :/

Comment: You didn't remove "pull-left"

Comment: yeah...I didn't do it remotely and forgot to upload it :D
but I found the bug...it was because of the
<div class="col-lg-3">
     <div class="col-md-12">
the col-md-12 override it on smaller views....I've put col-xs-12 and now it works great. :)

Thank you again :)

Comment: do you know how I can hide my background on extra small screen? I know I need a media query for that but don't know how to set it up and also how can I fix the top margin of my carousel (small and medium screen) and container (extra small screen) so the navbar doesn't overflow it. I would appreciate it if you can help me with this one out ^^

Comment: Use like in Bootstrap. @media (min-width: 768px) {}. Add your CSS with different attributes.